# Complex subversion 1.4 merge

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I've had a long-running feature branch that needs to be merged back into the trunk.  But I'm having a heck of a time getting the incantation right, and I could use a little help.

the log from my feature branch looks like this (I'm simplifying to keep this easier):

```
r170 fixed bug in boppity.py and snafu.py
r160 merged trunk revisions 131-159
r150 added boppity.py
r140 fixed bug in snafu.py
r130 merged trunk revisions 100-129
r120 fixed bug in foobar.py
r110 added foobar.py and snafu.py
r100 branch created
```

So what I *think* I want to do is merge 100-120, 130-150, 170.  I don't think I want to merge 130 or 160 because those changes already exist in both places and will most likely give me tree conflicts.

(And for those of you who are wondering why I don't use the "reintegrate" feature, it's because my subversion server is still 1.4, so it does not have that feature, AFAIK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge all revisions from trunk into your branch, and resolve all conflicts

If you are still using SVN 1.4 look close for all renames as they are not correctly merged.

After this,  do a merge by diffing your branch and trunk and apply it to your trunk.

[Look here for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386747/dont-diff-merges-with-svn/7387277#7387277)

Comment: ahhh, that's so much simpler.  Thanks for putting my head straight.   Incidentally, for future reference, the merge command is "svn merge trunkURL branchURL --ignore-ancestry trunkWCdirectory".